# extjs tree using cntl x and v

Tags: tree, extjs

I have a client that is requesting to be able to cut and paste inside a extjs tree.  I know i can replicate the actions using appendchild and removechild, but how can i associate the functions i make with ctrl x and v?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Ext.KeyMap](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.KeyMap). Also you can use some external scripts, for example [this one](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/). But there may be some conflicts of the last one with ExtJS, I never tried it with ExtJS.